# can we use structs for uniforms in GLSL-ES

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to use structs for the uniforms in my vertex shader in ES:

```
    struct temp{
        mat4 mvp;
    };
    uniform temp MP;
    in vec2 inPos;
    void main() {
         vec4 vert = MP.mvp * vec4(inPos.x,inPos.y,0,1);

        gl_Position = vert;
}
glGetUniformLocation(program, "MP.mvp");
```

it does not display any thing on screen, neigther any glerror. is it allowed in glsl es 300?

It works with OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

From [The OpenGL ES Shading Language v3.00](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.3.pdf), in section `4.3.5 Uniform Variables` it states:

> The **uniform** qualifier can be used with any of the basic data types, or when declaring a variable whose type is a structure, or an array of any of these.

If `glGetUniformLocation(program, "MP.mvp")` is returning 0 or greater then what you've shared so far looks legit. You'll probably have to post more code to get to the bottom of it.

If your struct only has a `mat4` in it then I would recommend just eliminating the struct altogether.